# How Do I Manually create /usr/local/lib

Tags: operating-system

Trying to install Homebrew but get the following error
mkdir: /usr/local/lib: Not a directory

Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/lib

Someone asked me to create the Lib folder manually and try reinstalling

Comment: have u actually tried to access /usr/local to check that it actually exists?

Comment: This should work as you have it. Are you sure mkdir is in /bin? it is often in /usr/bin and linked to from bin. the -p switch should create the entire folder hierarchy if it doesn't exist. If it does exist, mkdir will just quietly exit. Does lib exist in /usr/local as a file? If that were the case the error should read "File exists"